# Form submit only on second click Jquery

Tags: jquery, post, form-submit

have simple form, post with Jquery, after success validation, must click 2 times, to submit form:

Here is code of script tag:

```
(function($, window) {

    var dev = '.dev'; //window.location.hash.indexOf('dev') > -1 ? '.dev' : '';

    window.applyValidation = function(validateOnBlur, forms, messagePosition) {
        if( !forms )
            forms = 'form';
        if( !messagePosition )
            messagePosition = 'top';

        $.validate({
            form : forms,
            validateOnBlur : validateOnBlur,
            errorMessagePosition : messagePosition,
            scrollToTopOnError : true,


            onSuccess : function($form) {


            $( "#contactform").submit(function( event ) {
                 // event.preventDefault();

                var $form = $( this );

             first_name=$form.find( "input[name='first_name']" ).val();
             last_name=$form.find( "input[name='last_name']" ).val();


                     $.post("someurl",( $('#contactform').serialize()+'&'+$.param({ data1: data1, data2: data1 })))
          .done(function( data ) {
            alert( "hi: " + data1e + ' ' + data2 " );
          });
        });
                  return false;
                        }

                    });
                }; 


    window.applyValidation(true, '#contactform', 'element');


})(jQuery, window);
```

now, any idea how to mark witch mail is sent, and after finish first loop, continue sending mail.

After all mails sent,reset that,and go from beggining.

I have idea, to put one more filed, and set 1 if is set,0 if not send,but just to see any other idea.

Tnx

Comment: What library do you use? What is `$.validate`?

Comment: <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form-validator.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>

Comment: this line appears to be invalid: `$.post("http://someurl.com", $('#contactform').serialize()));` is that a typo or just an error with that extra closing `)` there?

Comment: I found this on internet, problem start when add :  $( "#contactform").submit(function( event ) function, before that, with alert('success'), get alert on succes validation

Comment: @pavlenko Can you show us the site of that plugin? There're many plugins called form validator, and I don't now where did you get `jquery.form-validator.js`.

Comment: I am searching too :) USe this for couple of times:)

Comment: @ Mark Schultheiss I edited question,with part of code that you mention. But all is fine, when click 2 times,get what I need

Comment: Note now this line has possible syntax error: `alert( "hi: " + data1e + ' ' + data2 " );` with that last double quote in there...

Comment: @ Mark Schultheiss , code working good, but only on second click on button, that is problem ,after first click,nothing happend,on secon click, form is submitted

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
$( "#contactform").submit(function( event ) {
    //  This line >> event.preventDefault();
    var $form = $( this );
```

This make problem, just remove these lines and working good...
Tnx ,